# One form and validation for many objects with different data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to check that form is valid in js file, but for many objects? I want to have only one form in html and don't use any of ng-repeats or other loops in html, then check form is valid for all objects.

Exmaple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="AngularApp">
<head>
    <script        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js">    </script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="mainController">
  Click on table row if u want to change data in form
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Index
        </td>

        <td>
          Name
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="element in testCollection"
          ng-click="changeActiveElement(element)">
        <td>{{ $index }}</td>
        <td>{{ element.name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br />
  <br />
  <br />

  <form name="exampleForm">
    <div class="row">
      Name [required]: <input type="text" ng-model="activeObject.name" required>
      </div>

    <div class="row">
    Phone [required]: <input type="text" ng-model="activeObject.phone" required>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      Active: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="activeObject.active">
    </div>
  </form>

  <br />

  <button ng-disabled="">
    This button should be enable if all objects from table will pass form validation
  </button>

  but how to do this? Button should be know that every form is good or not, even if won't change object by clicking on table row.
</body>
</html>
```

Js:

```
var app = angular.module("AngularApp", []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.testCollection = [
    {
      name: 'Mike',
      phone: 12345678,
      active: true
    },
    {
      name: 'Martin',
      phone: '',
      active: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Anna',
      phone: '',
      active: ''
    }
  ];

  $scope.activeObject = $scope.testCollection[0];

  $scope.changeActiveElement = function(element) {
    $scope.activeObject = element;
  };
});
```

Comment: can you provide sample html and code, and explain what you mean?

Comment: ok, give me a second

Comment: paste code here also, not only link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible, so lets say that 'many objects' are like this :

```
$scope.fianlObject = { manyObj1 : {}, manyObj2 :{}}
```

then do something like this with HTML :

```
<form id="frm1" name="frm1" ng-submit="submit()">
  <div class="form-group required" ng-class="isInvalid('manyObj1', form1)">
   ....
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required" ng-class="isInvalid('manyObj2', form1)">
   ....
  </div>
  .
  .
</form>
```

and something like this with script :

```
$scope.isInvalid = function (manyObj, form) {
            if (form&& form.$submitted) {
                return ( form[manyObj] && form[manyObj].$invalid) ? 'has-error'
                        : '';
                }
                return '';
            }
```

Comment: waht is _ctrl_ in your sample? you not define it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Angular have [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController), that have property [$invalid](http://$invalid)

> **$invalid**
>   *boolean*
>   *True* if at least one containing control or form is invalid.

and you can use it like

```
<button ng-disabled="formName.$invalid" ... >
```

Comment: this is good but only for object which is displayed in form, I want to make this button for all objects.

Comment: @Marcin, i not quite understand what you mean: from controller check value for all inputs inside, and if find at least one - set this property to _true_.

Comment: @Marcin, methinks i almost understood what you mean

Comment: @Marcin but i not understand this _don't use any of ng-repeats or other loops_ but you already use it _<tr ng-repeat="element in testCollection"_. So you can just repeat all elements inside form, and just show or hide it depends on what selected, in this case - form would be check all

Comment: this is good but wont it just disable the submit button untill $invalid is false, you could however say its the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

Just specify you validator function as a **pure** function which just accepts a plain object with the data and returns an array of errors (empty if everything is ok). This function should know about context it's used in.

Simple example:

```
function validateForm(data) {
    var errors = [];
    if (data.name === 'Joe') errors.push("You can't be Joe!");
    return errors;
}
```

Then, every time you want to validate your form, convert your form data to JS object and use the function. Also, you can use such function in any other context, no matter who is initiator of the validation.